# Programmatically traverse through roads on maps (google, here or open street)

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, here-api

**Background:**
I am trying to traverse through roads programmatically. I am inclined to use here.com maps but open street maps or google maps would also do. Programming language is also open, I am inclined towards Java, but Python, Go or another language would also do.

**Questions:**
Is there an API from a map provider which would let me traverse through a road network?

**Detail:**
I have GPS point cloud on streets in a big database. The data is not sorted in anyway, I want to evaluate each point by traversing through the road network. **I need to find holes on streets where we don't have any data.**

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Fleet Telematics Route Matching: 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here's an updated link for the Fleet Telematics API: https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/index.html